# Selenium is not finding a element

Tags: java, selenium, webdriver

For some reason, Selenium do not find a element anymore, i'm getting java.lang.NullPointerException. I'm getting the locator in a class through the xpath. When i search the xpath in the html, i get just one result, so, it should be founded.

This is the html where the element is:

```html
<input type="text" class="form-control app-header-page-search-field ng-pristine ng-untouched ng-valid" placeholder="Nome do produto, marca ou sku:123" ng-model="vm.search" ng-model-options="{ debounce: 200 }" uib-typeahead="ngram for ngramResults in vm.getAutocompleteItems($viewValue)"
typeahead-template-url="/app/_template/typeahead-match.template.html" typeahead-popup-template-url="/app/_template/typeahead-popup.template.html" ng-enter="" typeahead-on-select="vm.autocompleteSelect($item)" typeahead-no-results="noResults" aria-autocomplete="list"
aria-expanded="false" aria-owns="typeahead-36-8683">
```

This is the method from the Page Class:

```
@FindBy(xpath = "//span[text() = 'Produtos']")
@CacheLookup
private WebElement produtos;

public Produtos clickProdutos(){
       wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOf(produtos));
       produtos.click();
       return new Produtos(driver, wait);
}
```

And this is how i call this Method in my @Test method.

```
@Test
public void runTestCheckProdutos(){

    Home home = new Home(driver, wait);
    home.clickProdutos();
```

Comment: Where do you get NPE ? At which line exactly ? Is `produtos` variable declared anywhere ? I can't see a declaration in your code.

Comment: I thought you are looking for busca element but clicking productos. 
wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOf(busca));
       busca.click();

Comment: My bad, i've posted the wrong FindBy hehe. Edited with the correct (produtos)

Answer (score 0):

I think you are clicking on wrong object. (May productos may not even initialized)

```
wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOf(busca));
busca.click();
```